# How to set start time for primefaces clock widget?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, clock

Is it possible to set start time for PrimeFaces clock widget?
I know about Analog Clock from PrimeFaces Extensions, but I need digital clock with this option.
I have tried to override javascript method for this clock, but it doesn't work.

```
  PrimeFaces.widget.Clock = PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend({

    init: function(cfg) {
        this._super(cfg);

        this.cfg.value = 1430304817141;
        this.current = this.isClient() ? new Date() : new Date(this.cfg.value);
        var $this = this;

    },

    isClient: function() {
        return this.cfg.mode === 'client';
    },

});
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? Where do you try overriding the script and how?

Comment: I have tried to override this method in $(document).ready function - init method not called.

Comment: Post your overriding code.

Comment: code posted above.
`this.cfg.value` is default time and here this value is overrided `this.cfg.value = 1430304817141;`
and then try to setup this value here `this.current = this.isClient() ? new Date() : new Date(this.cfg.value);`

Comment: So you're not overriding a method, you're overriding a widget? In `$(document).ready` it probably overrides after the widgets were created by PrimeFaces. Try overriding in `h:head` without waiting for the `ready` event.

Comment: I have tried this. Widget doesn't show time.
[link](http://i.imgur.com/XXNxW03.png)

Answer (score 2):

The first problem was that you were overriding the widget too late, after PrimeFaces has instantiated its original unmodified widget. According to [PrimeFaces Customizable Resource Ordering](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1433) the right place to override would be in `h:head`.
The second problem is that you're overriding the widget with a crippled version, that doesn't contain many necessary functions that were present in the original widget.

I wouldn't recommend this approach at all - to basically break the whole PrimeFaces widget like that. What if you'd want to use the normal unchanged clock? Copy-pasted code is harder to maintain too. I advise going the more localized approach: tweak only a single widget instance.

```
<p:clock id="my_clock" />
<script>
    // get widgetVar via EL function, since p:clock doesn't have the widgetVar attribute
    var myClockVar = #{p:widgetVar('my_clock')};
    myClockVar.current = new Date(1430304817141);
</script>
```

Just be careful not to update the clock with AJAX requests, or it will to reset to showing client time; and not to update the script, or the clock will reset to the specified time again.