# Can we get date and time from primefaces clock and set it to a variable?

Tags: primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5.2.

Is it possible to get date and time from `p:clock` (client side) and set it to a variable?

Comment: Can you use JavaScript in answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941602/how-to-set-start-time-for-primefaces-clock-widget and set it to hidden p:calendar assigned to date variable

Comment: System clock? A widget clock? What clock?

Comment: @Miguel i think the client clock in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/clock.xhtml judging by his history of questions

Comment: @Miguel primefaces clock i.e., <p:clock />

Comment: @Kukeltje Question edited..

Comment: Clientside it is all html. So you can always do some dom action to get the value…  what did you try?

Comment: I tried this-- var myClockVar = #{p:widgetVar('admHomeForm:clockID')};

Comment: @Kukeltje Can you provide any samples regarding this?

Comment: what happened when you tried that... Please take a little more initiative...

Comment: @Kukeltje using myClockVar object i don't know how to get the value